# How to take data from Barcode scanner (USB) to a web App (browser Web-server)

Tags: javascript, php, rest, web-applications, barcode-scanner

In these days I read a lot of question on stackoverflow and other websites but none of them help me resolving the problem.

I want multiple barcode scanners to read barcodes on a client of a web Application.
Without interrupting each other!

I read there are two main solution about reading barcodes with scanners:

1 - keyboard wedge

2 - serial port

I first tryed the keyboard solution with javascript.

I gave to scanners readers prefix and suffix based on the position: $1barcode$1 , $2barcode$2..
and a timeout to distinguish scanner reads from keyboard ones.

The problem is that when more than one scanner read at the same time the Reading is mixed and I can not distinguish keypress events from which scanner is from. So it's not possible this way.

It works good with 1 barcode reader, but I need multiple. I can not afford to create interruption between scanner.

So I'm thinking about the second option, serial port.
But here my lack of knowledge doesn't allow me to know which is the best option of technology (language) to use and if it integrates good with a client-server web app.

How can I:

1 - take data each time I scan from the USB

2 - give data to the server

3 - refresh the client

I want to send to the server the information each time I scan.
I know I can do it with PHP knowing the addres of the USB port.
So if I query with PHP file (saved on server) I think it might work, but the client it's not refreshing the page because I'm not sending a post/get request.

How do you think I should proceed?

PS. I can not using any external libraries. I want to be able to know everything is going on.

Thank you for your time!